# plot the table with colorized cells in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for ways to plot the tables with cells filled by colors in R environment. Dose somebody know how to make the this kind of plot in R, as shown below.

[image]

I can get the similar plot using ggplot2 package, but I'm unable to extend the lines of rows and colums.

Any help for this question will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would stick with the `knitr::kable` & `kableExtra` combination when it comes to HTML tables in R. You can refer to [this online documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html) and take a look at the example below, which is taken from the documentation.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

mtcars[1:5, 1:4] %>%
  mutate(
    car = row.names(.),
    mpg = color_tile("white", "orange")(mpg),
    cyl = cell_spec(cyl, angle = (1:5)*60, 
                    background = "red", color = "white", align = "center"),
    disp = ifelse(disp > 200,
                  cell_spec(disp, color = "red", bold = T),
                  cell_spec(disp, color = "green", italic = T)),
    hp = color_bar("lightgreen")(hp)
  ) %>%
  select(car, everything()) %>%
  kable(escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "3cm") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Hello" = 2, "World" = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance. I still want to plot the same table with the one shown above. But solutions have not been found so far.